# How many video and audio samples should be included in each mdat?

Tags: audio, video, containers, mp4, fmp4

I am creating a FMP4 with 2 tracks (one for video and one for audio). I trying to find out how many video samples should I include in the mdat and how many audio as well.

So my FMP4 has the following structure:

```
ftyp
moov
moof (track1 - video)
mdat (track1 - video)
moof (track2 - audio)
mdat (track2 - audio)
moof (track1 - video)
mdat (track1 - video)
moof (track2 - audio)
mdat (track2 - audio)
...
```

Should each video mdat have just 1 frame or an entire GOP?

Should each audio mdat have the respective audio samples of the previous video mdat or can I send as many audio samples I want (since audio samples are much smaller, I could send like 2 seconds of audio while the video mdat sent before has only 1 second of duration).

PS: I thought in sending the entire GOP on each video mdat but I noticed that when I recode that fmp4 using ffmpeg, it makes so that the mdat has only 1 frame. I can do that (have just 1 video frame on each mdat), but then I am lost on how many audio samples should I send. If I send only the respective audio samples for that 1 video frame, the audio doesn't play very well.

Thanks!

Comment: @szatmary any suggestion?

Comment: You could try: For each video frame there is two audio frames (either before or after video). Every once in a while, you'll have to send only one audio frame with a video frame in order to keep synchronization. Check online how to calculate an MPEG audio frame's length (in milliseconds) since depends on audio settings. By knowing how many milliseconds your audio or your video frame lasts (its frame length in time) then you can know how many units to fit per second...

Comment: PS: **(1)** See if the [MP4 `trun` box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-sstr/6d796f37-b4f0-475f-becd-13f1c86c2d1f) has useful info to you. **(2)** _"I could send like 2 seconds of audio while the video mdat sent before has only 1 second of duration"_ Just experiment and take notes, see how a decoder responds to  timestamps in the a/v data (maybe an MPEG decoder's job is to cache input frames and only display at the specified composition time).

Comment: @VC.One, thanks for the suggestions. My audio is AAC so it has fixed duration (each frame has 21.33ms per frame since its sampling rate is 48000Hz). I was curious about if there is any restriction, but from your response it appears that it really depends and it is up to me how to send it, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From several empirical testing using ffmpeg, it appears that it likes to group 0.5s of video frames followed by 0.5s of audio frames and that appears to work really well.

Answer (score 0):

You are free to choose the grouping and it can be as is simple as one frame/packet per box. The grouping is going to matter to reader since it will likely prefer to read full box before starting processing.

Comment: Yes, you can group it using different combinations, but depending on how you group it will impact the performance of the reader, causing video/audio issues.

Comment: Decent reader/demultiplxer implementations accept any grouping

Comment: From my testings, VLC and HTLM5 video tag (Chrome) don't perform well with any grouping.

Comment: You are playing it close to live edge, aren't you? I remember Chrome specifically to parse well single packet mdat, however not video+audio muxed.

Comment: Correct, live stream.

Comment: So by grouping into 0.5s batches you are "buying" some buffering time to compensate inefficiency of [browser & VLC] players. Makes sense, even though it's obviously player issue, not yours.